# Is it possible to query multiple datastore keys in single query?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I couldn't find this in documentation. I'm checking the existance of multiple keys in datastore in single AppEngine request. Is it possible to do this in a single query, since this would be much more efficient then sending multiple get_by_id requests?

Comment: You can use : db.get(list_of_keys) and in NDB: ndb.get_multi(list_of_keys)

Comment: thanks. is there any difference in behavior between these two? can i do keys_only with get_multi (to only check for item existance)?

Comment: NDB has a lot of benefits, like caching. The keys_only query option returns keys. But why a key_only query if you use the keys you provide to query? You have the keys.

Comment: But you can try if it makes sense to test for the existence only. But I do not understand what you try to accomplish.

Comment: well i'm using custom string keys and, for a set of strings, will be checking which ones exist and which ones don't (there'll be a lot of them each time, so i needed an optimal method). i'll try it out, thank you for clearing things up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Create a RPC request to get entities by key with lookup method of Google Cloud Datastore:

```
request = datastore.LookupRequest()
request.key.extend(list_of_keys)
response = datastore.lookup(request)
```

Or faster:

```
list_of_entities = ndb.get_multi(list_of_keys)
```